# Can a Tomcat web application tell a load balancer its Tomcat is down?

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have two Tomcat servers deployed behind an Nginx load balancer that's using `proxy_pass` to route the requests. This works well, but there is now an use case in my application for which I need to pull one of the servers out of the cluster (but keep it running), have the web application on it do something and when that's done place the Tomcat back.

Right now I'm reloading the Nginx configuration manually and mark the server `down` to give time to the application to do its thing, but what **I would like is have the web application "trick" Nginx that its Tomcat server is down**, do it's stuff, then rejoin the cluster.

I'm thinking that I need to have some custom Tomcat Connector that's controlled by the web application but everything online is about proxying with Apache or using AJP and that's not what I need, I need this to be a HTTP proxy with Nginx.

Anyone has some pointers on how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try max_fails and fail_timeout configuration of [Upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream), for instance

```
upstream backend {
  server tomcat1.localhost max_fails=3 fail_timeout=15s;
  server tomcat2.localhost max_fails=3 fail_timeout=15s;
}
```

UPDATE:

To solve "mark as down by demand" task you can put maintenance.html file into the public directory, handle it via "try files" and produce error code 503 if the file exists. It helps you to configure balancer efficiently.

Comment: I don't know if this answers my question, please read the question again. I've reworded it to make it more clear.

Comment: @JohnDoDo it's not a bit clear, especially the term "trick". Do you intend to be able manually stop sending traffic through without Nginx configuration update? Sometihng like "mark as down" via HTTP request?

Comment: I want Nginx to think Tomcat is down when in fact it is not. I want the web application inside Tomcat to somehow interpose itself between Nginx and Tomcat and when Nginx verifies the connection to Tomcat, the web application to not respond or respond with a message saying "not available" or something.

Comment: @JohnDoDo yes, that's why I put an update to my answer up above. The  code example is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/310819/maintenance-page-on-nginx-best-practices

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When tomcat goes down, your webapp will go with it - you shouldn't rely on it to do any meaningful work to delay the shutdown. Rather have proper systems management procedures to first change the LB, then shutdown tomcat. That's a solution external to tomcat - and should be easy as you say that you pull one of the tomcats from your cluster.

For unplanned downtimes, use the LB's detection of tomcat being down, like @mikhailov described.

Comment: I don't want to stop the Tomcat, that's the catch. I want it to stay up but the application on it to tell Nginx that the Tomcat is unavailable. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: IMHO it's not the responsibility of the webapp to configure its loadbalancer - that's rather part of the underlying system administration system (how do you start your nginx? change its configuration?). Get away from assuming that it needs to be directly controlled by the webapp and think of all other triggers (e.g. planned downtime, resilience tests etc). In the end, your webapp might "give hints" to whatever system you're using, but it doesn't directly control nginx. That's too tight a coupling.

Comment: I'm in perfect agreement with your comment but all I want to do is tell to the LB that the server is down, when in fact it isn't. That's it. And it has to be done by the web application (long story...) not by Tomcat actually going down. I'm not controlling Nginx through the web application, I want to avoid that in fact.